# Is there a way to understand which executors were used for a job in java/scala code?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm having trouble evenly distributing streaming receivers among all executors of a yarn-cluster.
I've got a yarn-cluster with 8 executors, I create 8 streaming custom receivers and spark is supposed to launch these receivers one per executor. However this doesn't happen all the time and sometimes all receivers are launched on the same executor (here's the jira bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10730).
So my idea is to run a dummy job, get the executors that were involved in that job and if I got all the executors, create the streaming receivers.
For doing that anyway I need to understand if there is a way to understand which executors were used for a job in java/scala code.

Comment: Here you have a link from DataBriks that explains really well how to follow a job's lifecycle in a Spark cluster https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html

Comment: I need to do it in the java/scala code. I've added this detail to the question

Comment: If you check out the databricks link in my previous comment it will help you  understand how to use Spark UI tools to see how a job is processed across the cluster and which executors are involved.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is possible to look what executors where doing what jobs by accessing *Spark UI* and *Spark* logs. From the official `1.5.0` documentation ([here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)):

> Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040, that displays useful information about the application. This includes:
>
> - A list of scheduler stages and tasks
> - A summary of RDD sizes and memory usage
> - Environmental information.
> - Information about the running executors

In the following screen you can see what executors are active. In case there are cores/nodes that are not being used, you can detect them by just looking what cores/nodes *are actually* active and running.

In addition, every executor displays information about the number of tasks that are being running on it.

[image]